# Prove that $\sum_{r=2}^{n} \left \lfloor n^{\frac{1}{r}} \right \rfloor = \sum_{r=2}^{n} \left \lfloor \log_{r}(n) \right \rfloor$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that
$$\sum_{r=2}^{n} \left \lfloor n^{\frac{1}{r}} \right \rfloor = \sum_{r=2}^{n} \left \lfloor \log_{r}(n) \right \rfloor\,.$$

---

I have tried to use substitutions of $n=p^k$ in order to try and simplify, but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere, I'm not entirely sure how I can get around the floor functions.

Comment: Let $$S_n:=\Big\{ (r,k)\,\Big|\,k,r\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}\text{ and }k^r\leq n\Big\}\,.$$
Count in to ways.  For each $k\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$, there are $$\big\lfloor \log_k(n)\big\rfloor-1$$ values of $r$ such that $(r,k)\in S_n$.  For each $r\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$, there are $$\left\lfloor n^{\frac1r}\right\rfloor-1$$ values of $k$ such that $(r,k)\in S_n$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcKe2nx8A4g
Hint: Think about the relation of $n^{\frac{1}{r}}$ and $\log_r(n)$.

Comment: @Batominovski  Why do you subtract $1$ from $\lfloor \log_k (n) \rfloor $ to get the possible values of $r$ for each $k$ ? Is it because $1$ is not there ?

Comment: @user710290  Yes, it is to ignore $1$.

Comment: @Batominovski Why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @Chrystomath  I predict that this thread will be deleted anyhow.  As far as I am concerned, Math.SE doesn't value answers very much.